# How to increment count in the replacement string when using preg_replace?

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-replace

I have this code :

```
$count = 0;    
preg_replace('/test/', 'test'. $count, $content,-1,$count);
```

For every replace, I obtain test0.

I would like to get test0, test1, test2 etc..

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php):

```
$count = 0;
preg_replace_callback('/test/', 'rep_count', $content);

function rep_count($matches) {
  global $count;
  return 'test' . $count++;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Use [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php):

```
class TestReplace {
    protected $_count = 0;

    public function replace($pattern, $text) {
        $this->_count = 0;
        return preg_replace_callback($pattern, array($this, '_callback'), $text);
    }

    public function _callback($matches) {
        return 'test' . $this->_count++;
    }
}

$replacer = new TestReplace();
$replacer->replace('/test/', 'test test test'); // 'test0 test1 test2'
```

---

Note: Using `global` is the hard-and-fast solution but it introduces some problems, so I don't recommend it.

Comment: Global has no more problems than the overcomplicated object solution. People get stuck on globals in PHP because of the C/C++/etc stigmatism, which is misplaced. Globals in PHP are simply request-scoped variables. Less hand-wringing, more pragmatism.

Comment: A CLASS here is not needed and may confuse the answer for this question. You just may give a clean example of using "preg_replace_callback"

Answer (score 4):

Following the release of PHP5.3 we can now use a closure and the `use` keyword to get around the `global` issue raised by Emil above:

```
    $text = "item1,\nitem2,\nFINDME:23623,\nfoo1,\nfoo2,\nfoo3,\nFINDME:923653245,\nbar1,\nbar2,\nFINDME:43572342,\nbar3,\nbar4";
$pattern = '/FINDME:(\d+)/';
$count = 1;
$text = preg_replace_callback(  $pattern
                            ,   function($match) use (&$count) {
                                    $str = "Found match $count: {$match[1]}!";
                                    $count++;
                                    return $str;
                                }
                            ,   $text
                            );
echo "<pre>$text</pre>";
```

Which returns:

```
item1,
item2,
Found match 1: 23623!,
foo1,
foo2,
foo3,
Found match 2: 923653245!,
bar1,
bar2,
Found match 3: 43572342!,
bar3,
bar4
```

Note the `use (&$count)` following the function name - this allows us to read `$count` in the scope of the function (the & making it passed by reference and therefore writeable from the scope of the function).

Answer (score 3):

Also, if you want to avoid using global:

`$count = 0;
preg_replace_callback('/test/', function rep_count($matches) use (&$count) {
  return 'test' . $count++;
}, $content);`

Answer (score 3):

You only have to define a static variable in the callback function:

```
$result = preg_replace_callback('/test/', function ($m) {
    static $count = 0;
    return 'test' . $count++;
}, $content);
```

This way you don't pollute the global namespace.

---

For this specific case you can also use simple functions:

```
$parts = explode('test', $content);
$end = array_pop($parts);
$result = '';

foreach($parts as $k=>$v) {
    $result .= 'test' . $k;
}

$result .= $end;
```

Answer (score 2):

[`preg_replace_callback()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) will allow you to operate upon the match before returning it for subsequent replacement.