# Laravel undefined variable ID Controller

Tags: php, laravel-4

I am getting below error:

> ErrorException (E_UNKNOWN)  Undefined variable: id

below is my code, It is from "Controller"

```html
public function show($id)
 {
  if(Auth::user()) {
   $message = Message::where(function($query) {
    $query->where('from_user', '=', Auth::user()->username)->where('id', '=', $id);
   })->orWhere(function($query) {
    $query->where('from_user', '=', Auth::user()->username)->where('id', '=', $id);
   });
   if($message == null) {
    return Redirect::action('MessageController@index');
   }
   return View::make('view', ['message' => $message, 'active' => 'none']);
  }
 }
```

**Update:** My Route is : `Route::get('/message/{id}', 'MessageController@show')->before('auth');`

I could not understand, what i am messing with up, I have already passed `$id` in function argument.

Comment: When you call `show` are you sure that the `$id` parameter is not null?

Comment: what is your route for show action ?

Comment: Your route should be like this Route::get('show/{id}', 'YourController@show');

Comment: @ecnepsnai , That is obvious . My Route is using {id}

Comment: I don;t know why skids think, they are genius and rates -1 , where answer is some real missing thing, that they are not aware of either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you didn't. 
Variable `$id` is passed to the function `show()` while you trying to use it inside lambda function passed to the `where()`/`orWhere()` method.
If you wish to use inside lambda function variable from outer scope you should use `use($variableName)` construct.

Instead of `function($query) {` use `function($query) use($id) {`

Relate answer about `use`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8403958/882813
Bear in mind variable early binding.