# acess variable in sub function

Tags: php, function

I made this function and observed there was an issue during it execution.
I'm not able to get the result of `$names_from_source` inside the sub function.
There is no error, it detects the variable but it value is always NULL.

```
/*
source: array of MyObject
copy: array of MyObject
return: return duplicated objects based on name
*/
function get_all_duplicated($source, $copy) {
    $names_from_source = array_map(fn($obj): string => $obj->name, $source);
    var_dump($names_from_source); // return list of names
    return array_filter($copy, function($obj) {
        global $names_from_source;
        var_dump($names_from_source); // return NULL
        return in_array($obj->name, $names_from_source);
    });
}
```

Why?
Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing outside variable using anonymous function as params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8403908/accessing-outside-variable-using-anonymous-function-as-params)

Comment: Yes I was just writing same XD thanks to you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

global couldn't be used because `$names_from_source` isn't a global variable.
It is a local variable from parent function.

to call it in sub function I have to use the term `use`

```
/*
source: array of MyObject
copy: array of MyObject
return: return duplicated objects based on name
*/
function get_all_duplicated($source, $copy) {
    $names_from_source = array_map(fn($obj): string => $obj->name, $source);
    var_dump($names_from_source); // return list of names
    return array_filter($copy, function($obj) use($names_from_source) {
        return in_array($obj->name, $names_from_source);
    });
}
```