# Replacing text using a loop in PHP

Tags: php, preg-match

I am trying to loop through every `[footnote]` and replace it with some HTML. Here is some sample text:

```
Hello [footnote], how are you [footnote], what are you up to [footnote]?
```

And using preg_match_all to create a count:

```
$match_count = preg_match_all("/\[footnote]/", $content);
```

I then use this count as a loop, to find and replace the text with appropriate HTML:

```
for ($i=0; $i < $match_count; $i++) { 
   $new_content = str_replace('[footnote]', "<span class='footnote'>$i</span>", $content);
}
```

However, after, when I `echo $new_content;` each `[footnote]` has the same number, **2**:

```
<span class="footnote">2</span>
<span class="footnote">2</span>
<span class="footnote">2</span>
```

Would anyone know why this number is not incrementing? This is what I want

```
<span class="footnote">1</span>
<span class="footnote">2</span>
<span class="footnote">3</span>
```

Comment: `str_replace` replaces everything at once, you need `preg_replace` with a limit.

Comment: Could you show or link to an example?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to increment count in the replacement string when using preg\_replace?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184601/how-to-increment-count-in-the-replacement-string-when-using-preg-replace)

Answer (score 1):

**you can do like this**

```
$i = 0;
preg_replace_callback('/[footnote]/', 'replaces_counter', $content);

function replaces_counter($matches) {
  global $i;
  return "<span class='footnote'>".$i++."</span>";
}
```

Comment: What does the `$matches` parameter do here?

Answer (score 0):

`str_replace` replaces everything at once, you need `preg_replace` which supports `$limit` (=number of replacements to make):

```
$content = "Hello [footnote], how are you [footnote], what are you up to [footnote]?";

$i = 0;
do {
    $i++;
    $content = preg_replace('~\[footnote\]~', "<span>$i</span>", $content, 1, $count);
} while($count);

print $content;
```

Note that the 5th parameter, `$count` makes your counting code superfluous - we just keep replacing until no more replacement could be made.

Comment: Thanks, what are `~` on either side for?

Comment: @tmyie: regular expression syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to replace a literal string, you can avoid to use a regex. Example:

```
$str = 'Hello [footnote], how are you [footnote], what are you up to [footnote]?';

$arr = explode('[footnote]', $str);
$count = 1;

$result = array_reduce($arr, function ($carry, $item) use (&$count) {
     return (isset($carry)) 
         ? $carry . '<span class="footnote">' . $count++ . '</span>' . $item
         : $item;   
});

print_r($result);
```