# str_replace() with 3 different replaces

Tags: php, wordpress, str-replace

I have this PHP Code for add a specific class to `<a>` element in a WordPress menú, before to clean all other elements from WordPress:

```
<?php 

$menuParameters = array(
  'menu' => '40',
  'container'       => false,
  'echo'            => false,
  'items_wrap'      => '%3$s',
  'depth'           => 0,
);

$menu = strip_tags(wp_nav_menu( $menuParameters ), '<a>' );

$find = array('<a');
$replace = array('<a class="pro-link pro1"');
echo str_replace( $find, $replace, $menu );

?>
```

This print some like this:

```
<a class="pro-link pro1" href="link1">Link1</a>
<a class="pro-link pro1" href="link2">Link2</a>
<a class="pro-link pro1" href="link3">Link3</a>
```

The problem is that I need to put 3 distinct classes (**pro1, pro2 and pro3**), and print like this:

```
<a class="pro-link pro1" href="link1">Link1</a>
<a class="pro-link pro2" href="link2">Link2</a>
<a class="pro-link pro3" href="link3">Link3</a>
```

How I can do it? I need to iterate?

Thanks for your help! :)

**UPDATE:**

It's working but the first item print only "pro", and the next "pro1", "pro2". I tried to change value of **$replacecounter** but it doesn't work. I need just solve that and will work perfect.

```
<?php 

$menuParameters = array(
  'menu' => '40',
  'container'       => false,
  'echo'            => false,
  'items_wrap'      => '%3$s',
  'depth'           => 0,
);

$replacecounter = 1;      

$menu = strip_tags(wp_nav_menu( $menuParameters ), '<a>' );                                                 

echo preg_replace_callback('/<a/', 'replaceCounter', $menu);

function replaceCounter() {
    global $replacecounter;
    $str="pro-link pro". $replacecounter++;
    return "<a class='$str'";
}

?>
```

Comment: Is there any loop?

Comment: loops comes to the rescue

Comment: You could put it in a loop and make 1 as a variable. For each iteration it adds 1 .

Comment: I tried to make a loop but i can't got it. May you explain please? Thanks!

Comment: please mention your existing html code or the $menu variable?

Comment: I updated the code with the complete sentence. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:[Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184601/how-to-increment-count-in-the-replacement-string-when-using-preg-replace) using [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php).On each match `replaceCounter` will be called and replaced value is returned.

```
$replacecounter = 1;
$str='<a  href="link1">Link1</a>
<a  href="link2">Link2</a>
<a  href="link3">Link3</a>';
echo preg_replace_callback('/<a/', 'replaceCounter', $str);

function replaceCounter() {
    global $replacecounter;
    $str="pro-link pro". $replacecounter++;
    return "<a class='$str'";
}
```

[DEMO](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b1b8d1005063c3c6510380ff9c425e157189dc61)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It's working but the first item print only "pro", and the next "pro1", "pro2". I tried to change value of $replacecounter but it doesn't work. I need just solve that and will work perfect.

Comment: @NachoSarmiento see the demo added it should work fine. i think you forgot to add `$replacecounter = 1;`.

Comment: I add an updated in my code, based in your reply. That's code I'm using now. Please check. Thanks you!

Comment: @NachoSarmiento it should work fine but if still you have issue you can try:`$str="pro-link pro". ++$replacecounter;`.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this, and it works for your presented case:

```
$menu="<a href=\"link1\">Link1</a>
<a href=\"link2\">Link2</a>
<a href=\"link3\">Link3</a>
";

$tip="<a href";
$tiplen=strlen($tip);
for($x=1; $x<4; ++$x){
    $menu=substr_replace($menu,"<a class=\"pro-link pro$x\" href",strpos($menu,$tip),$tiplen);
}
echo $menu;
```

or if not always 3 links...

```
$x=0;
$tip="<a href";
$tiplen=strlen($tip);
while(strpos($menu,$tip)!==false){
    $menu=substr_replace($menu,"<a class=\"pro-link pro".++$x."\" href",strpos($menu,$tip),$tiplen);
}
```