# Replacing occurrencies of element inside a string one by one adding an index

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I actually need to replace every occurrence of □□□ inside a string with "hello" and an index that increments for each occurence.

```
$text = "abc □□□ def □□□ ghi □□□";
$pattern = "/□□□/i";
$regex = preg_replace($pattern, "hello", $text);
```

With this code the *$regex* will look like this:

> *"abc hello def hello ghi hello"*

What I want is to make it look like this:

> *"abc hello1 def hello2 ghi hello3"*

How can I achieve that?

Is it possible to replace each occurrence one by one so I can insert this portion of code inside a for loop and add an index to the replacing string?

Comment: Older duplicate with more answers: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2184601/

Comment: Right, it is really a good one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `preg_replace_callback` and pass a counter into the anonmous function used as the replacement argument:

```php
$text = "abc □□□ def □□□ ghi □□□";
$pattern = "/□□□/i";
$counter = 1;
echo preg_replace_callback($pattern, function($m) use (&$counter) {
    return "hello" . $counter++;
    }, $text);
// => abc hello1 def hello2 ghi hello3
```

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/vn9ED).

Note that the `&` in front of `$counter` makes it possible to update this variable  value inside the replacement.